# Automatically display on-screen keyboard for all form items in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, accessibility

I'm trying to write a kiosk application using flex swf(not Adobe air). Is there a way to include an on-screen keyboard(a virtual keyboard is automatically displayed) for all form items in the application for every [view state](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63611-7ffa.html) wherever there is a [form](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextInput.html)/[textfield](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextArea.html) etc element. This is quite similar to android/ios apps where the OS pops up a keyboard wherever required for such controls?